# How to alter comments on columns after renaming table name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway

I'm using flyway to work with my database. 
I've changed a table name via:

```
 alter table tablename rename to table_name;
```

How do I change all the comments that I am currently have on all of the columns? 
Should I delete them and recreate or there is a specific alter comment sql command to do so in one line? 
Or they will adapt accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to `ALTER` a comment. Just use

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN table_name.colname IS '...';
```

to set the new comment. That will automatically overwrite the old comment.

Comments are not `ALTER`ed or `DROP`ped. To remove a comment, set it to NULL with `COMMENT ON`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is "moved" with the table renaming:

```
# select c.relname table_name, pg_catalog.obj_description(c.oid) as comment 
from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.relname = 'old';
 table_name |   comment   
------------+-------------
 old        | comment old
(1 row)

# alter table old rename to new;
ALTER TABLE

# select c.relname table_name, pg_catalog.obj_description(c.oid) as comment 
from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.relname = 'old';
 table_name | comment 
------------+---------
(0 rows)

# select c.relname table_name, pg_catalog.obj_description(c.oid) as comment 
from pg_catalog.pg_class c where c.relname = 'new';
 table_name |   comment   
------------+-------------
 new        | comment old
(1 row)

#
```

Comment: Does it mean that I only need to rename table itself, and comments will be updated automatically?

Comment: Yes: I have verified this for table comment and table columns comments.